# Jenkins Gradle build- string parameter not passing to java code

Tags: java, string, jenkins, gradle, parameter-passing

I have set Jenkins job as gradle build to run my java application.I set string parameter to get in my java code. My build.gradle file has following,

```
 // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'application'

    // In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/main/resources'
            }
        }
        test {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/test/java'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/test/resources'
            }
        }
```

In Java code i try to get value as ,

String env = System.getProperty("Environment") ;

but i get env value as null.

I'm new to Jenkins and gradle. Can anyone tell me how to get jenkins parameter value in my java code and why it is returning null `enter code here`value?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use -pEnvironment= value as a argument while running gradle task.
It will work for sure :)